# How do I center list of concatenated strings (with \n between each) in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, concatenation

I want to take a bunch of individual strings that are in an array and then concatenate them together and throw them into a textview.

If my array contained {item1, longitem2, i3}, I want the TextView to show as follows (centered in the view):

```
     item1
   longitem2
      i3
```

Here is my assignment code:

```
ArrayList<String> listArray = new ArrayList();    
StringBuffer listString = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < listArray.size(); i++) {
    listString.append(listArray.get(i)).append("\n");
}
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filtered_list);
textView.setText(listString);
```

And here is my XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filtered_list"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Placeholder\nPlaceholder2\nPlaceholder1000" />
```

I'd like for the list of output to be centered down the page.

I *know* that I could use a different view here (ListView) but am trying to keep it simple because this is just pure text output on which the user will not have any further interaction other than reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/filtered_list"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Placeholder\nPlaceholder2\nPlaceholder1000" />
```

Comment: YES!! that works perfectly. but i don't understand why :)

Comment: layout_width="fill_parent" is max width screen.

Comment: do note that fill_parent is deprecated as of API LEVEL 8. Use match_parent instead